# How to simplify without using the abc formula

Tags: factoring, algebra-precalculus

I usually use abc formula to simplify expressions. I'm simplifying $x^2-6x+10$. Using the abc formula I get a complex solution. I checked the answer and found theres a much simpler way to write it. How can I see that $x^2-6x+10 =(x-3)^2 +1$? Now that I have seen the answer I know it totally makes sense. But I want to see it before checking the answer.

Comment: Remember $(x-a)^2=x^2-2a+a^2$ and complete the square

Comment: Hint : $x^2-6x+10=(x-3)^2+1$

Comment: $x^2\color{red}{-6x}+10$, we turn our attention to the $-6x$ part.  Take half of the coefficient.  We'll try rewriting things using that.  So, we have $x^2+2\cdot (\color{red}{-3})x+\color{blue}{10}$.  We next turn our attention to rewriting the $+10$ using the square of the result we found earlier, in this case $(-3)^2=9$.  So, we now have $x^2+2\cdot (\color{red}{-3})x+(\color{red}{-3})^2+1$ noting that $10=9+1$.  We now recognize the first three terms as being of the usual $x^2+2xy+y^2$ form which is $(x+y)^2$, so we can now rewrite as $(x-3)^2+1$

Comment: The abc formula (most call it the quadratic formula) is really the general case of completing the square.

Answer (score 1):

$(x-a)^2=x^2-2a+a^2$, so if you have $x^2-bx+c$, it is $\left(x-\dfrac b2\right)^2+c-\left(\dfrac b2\right)^2.$